# IPhone app crash report

Tags: iphone

I am building an iphone app.However my app crashes at a point when i run simulator.I want to know the reason.But i don't know how to see crash logs. Please give me some information about how to see crash logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Xcode open the console Window and you will see the crash log.

Use this shortcut to view the console window if it's not already showing:

> Debug Area show/hide : ⇧ ⌘ Y

Answer (score 1):

Press the middle button of the view group buttons. It will bring the console and you will see if something happens.

[image: Pice of top bar]